# I can not get the number value contained within a <span> tag using javascript and Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

When I run the code the nameGen page evaluation returns a type error that states: "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null". The span tag it is targeting has a number value for price and that is what I am trying to get to.  How do I access the number value that is contained in the span tag I am targeting? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. The element I am targeting looks like this:

```html
<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">
    $44.99
</span>
```

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let nameArr = [];
const rand1 = Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8);
nameArr.push({ id: 1, link: `<img src ="${rand1}">` });
//creates a random string to used as the image name and pushes it to an array

amazonScraper = (url) =>{
  (async () => {
    let imageUrl = url ;
    let path = `./scrapers/amazonScrapers/imageScraper/screenshots`;
    //assign a name to url and the path for saving images

    let browser =  await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    //launch puppeteer

    await page.goto(imageUrl), { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' };
    //sends puppeteer to the url and waits until everything is rendered

    await page.waitForSelector('#landingImage');
    let element1 = await page.$('#landingImage');
    await element1.screenshot({ path: `${path}/${rand1}.png` });
    //screenshot the image

    let nameGen =await page.evaluate(() => {
      let name = document.getElementById('productTitle').innerHTML;
      return name;
    });
    // grabs name of the item

      let priceGen =await page.evaluate(() => {
      let price =  document.getElementById('priceblock_ourprice').innerHTML;
      return price;
    });
    //Broken: attempts to grab item price

    console.log(nameGen);
    console.log(priceGen);

    await browser.close();
    //closes puppeteer
})();
};

amazonScraper ("https://www.amazon.com/TOMLOV-Microscope-50X-1300X-Magnification-Ultra-Precise/dp/B08MVKKSLY/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=yqTTn&pf_rd_p=2eed4166-2052-4602-96d1-514e72c433c6&pf_rd_r=8E0WGYYVYE5017ECAJPG&pd_rd_r=03b5a7f9-3f43-4f72-b9c8-d3ec581b450c&pd_rd_wg=jBNiN&ref_=pd_gw_crs_wish");
//calling scraper function
```

Here is the error:

````
(node:11276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:66
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (c:\Users\grung\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (c:\Users\grung\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
    at async c:\Users\grung\javaScriptPractice\jsPractice\scrapers\amazonScrapers\imageScraper\scraper.js:32:21
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: What’s your question? Do you know in which case `document.getElementById` returns `null`?

Comment: I will adjust the question. The question is how do I access the number value that is contained in the span tag I am targeting?

Comment: What's your HTML structrue? Check the spelling of your Id.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this. I am sorry. I am still pretty new to coding. This is for scraping amazon website for the image, item name, and price. The price aspect is what I cannot get working. it is contained with in a span tag like so. 

```<span id="priceblock_ourprice" class="a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString">$44.99</span>
```

Comment: Your selector is missing the `#`: `document.querySelector('#priceblock_ourprice')`

Comment: I tried that and it still gives me an error. Thanks for the suggestion. I went in and edited the code with comments so it is a bit easier to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @rayhatfield He has added the `#` before.

Comment: It is a bit confusing because I have edited it a couple of times. This is my first post  and I did not do a very good job. The code as it is now is what I am working with and I added comments so my code is more clear. I am sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @grungeKarma Could you give a screenshoot of the error?

Comment: No problem. I will edit the question to include that text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

- you need to wait for the item to be available on the page. looks like the `priceblock_ourprice` is generated after the page is send to the client.

  In puppeteer, there's a build in function to wait for a certain selector:

  ```js
  let priceGen =await page
    .waitForSelector('#priceblock_ourprice')
    .evaluate(() => {
      let price =  document.getElementById('priceblock_ourprice').innerHTML;
      return price;
    });
  ```
- Amazon doesn't use a single id for pricing. There are several in use. some examples:

  - `priceblock_ourprice`
  - `priceblock_dealprice`

  So you probably need to account for those as well.
  You can wait for multiple items like this:

  ```js
  await page.waitForFunction((priceSelectors) =>
    document.querySelectorAll(priceSelectors).length, {}, priceSelectors
  )
  ```

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.amazon.com/Insect-Lore-Butterfly-Growing-Kit/dp/B00000ISC5?ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_a46a25b3_60&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER');

  const priceSelectors = [
    '#priceblock_ourprice',
    '#priceblock_dealprice' /* more here if you find more selectors */
  ];

  await page.waitForFunction((priceSelectors) =>
    document.querySelectorAll(priceSelectors).length,
    {},
    priceSelectors // pass priceSelectors to wairForFunction
  )
  const pricer = await page.evaluate((priceSelectors) => {
    const priceRegex = /^\D\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
    const asSingleSelector = priceSelectors.join(',');
    const priceElements = document.querySelectorAll(asSingleSelector);
    let price;
    priceElements.forEach((item) => {
      if (item && // item is not null
        item.innerHTML && // innerHTML exists
        priceRegex.test(item.innerHTML)) { // make sure string is a price
        price = item.innerHTML;
      }
    });
    return price;
  }, priceSelectors); // pass priceSelectors to evaluate

  console.log(pricer);

  await browser.close();

})();
```

If you don't find the price in a specific page, you probably missed a price selector for that specific scenario

Comment: I tried this solution after reviewing it and it makes sense to me but when i try to apply the code it throws the error. 

```c:\Users\grung\javaScriptPractice\jsPractice\scrapers\amazonScrapers\imageScraper\scraper.js:47
            priceRegex.test(item.innerHTML) { // make sure string is a price
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'```
I have only been coding a little over a month so I do not understand what is wrong with the structure, it looks fine to me.

Comment: I think it was missing a paren . But once I add it, the code throws all kinds of errors.

Comment: hey @grungeKarma . fixed all the problems you mentioned and made sure the code works. so everything should work fine for you now.

Comment: @grungeKarma If this helped, please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, this worked and I really appreciate it. After review, I understand what the code is doing. I do have one question. How did you know that Amazon needed multiple selectors before it can render the price? Was this knowledge you just had or were you able to tell from the structure of the page? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I will upvote once I have the power too. I need more repuatation.

Comment: @grungeKarma I tried looking at a random product page and noticed I don't find the selector from your question anywhere. I saw the price has a different id so I looked at different products and saw that based on the scenario, a different price with a different id is shown. If I was you, I would probably try and look for all price ids I can find, but will add more everytime I find another id I didn't think about. The other solution is using something different than the direct id. you can see that no matter what price is being used, it's always wrapped with `#price` id which you can always use.

Comment: @grungeKarma sure! glad I helped! :-)